# How can I effectively parse text into groups?

Tags: regex

I have a set of pdf invoices that need to parsed into respectove columns/groups like below:

[image]

[csv](https://gofile.io/d/VNL2qL)

To add text,

```
Data
28/06/22      7694759.0        Service Rear Lift 660L Cardboard                           1      $5.00            $5.00
30/06/22      7710113.0        Service Rear Lift 240L Co-Mingled           Bin Empty      1     $10.25           $10.25
28/06/22      7694756.0        Service Rear Lift 660L Putrescible                         2     $28.50           $57.00
30/06/22      7714583.0        Service Rear Lift 240L Putrescible                         1     $13.91           $13.91
Site: 111947.021 Rental Charge (H8.0 x 1 / RI) GRN (x 5)                              5       $10.00          $50.00
21/06/22     7648522.0   Futile Service Front Lift 1.5M mick-email  1   20  20
28/06/22     7686945.0   Removal Front Lift 4.5M Putrescible    full on removal 2   100 200
03/06/22     7537009.0  Service Rear Lift 240L Putrescible  JENNIFER    1   13.34   1.364
```

to be parsed into

```
Date            Site        Description                             Description_2   Qty Price   Total
28/06/22        7694759.0   Service Rear Lift 660L Cardboard                        1   5       5
30/06/22        7710113.0   Service Rear Lift 240L Co-Mingled       Bin Empty       1   10.25   10.25
28/06/22        7694756.0   Service Rear Lift 660L Putrescible                      2   28.5    57
30/06/22        7714583.0   Service Rear Lift 240L Putrescible                      1   13.91   13.91
                111947.021  Rental Charge (H8.0 x 1 / RI) GRN (x 5)                 5   10      50
21/06/22        7648522.0   Futile Service Front Lift 1.5M          mick-email      1   20      20
28/06/22        7686945.0   Removal Front Lift 4.5M Putrescible     full on removal 2   100     200
03/06/22        7537009.0   Service Rear Lift 240L Putrescible      JENNIFER        1   13.34   1.364
```

How can I perform the grouping in `regex`?

Comment: That pdf image looks like a screenshot of Excel, or similar. Is it an option to ask for the original data to be exported as CSV?

Comment: Sure. You can find the same [here](https://gofile.io/d/VNL2qL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^([\d\/]+)?\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s+([A-Za-z]\S+(?:\s\S+)*)\s+([A-Za-z]\S+(?:\s\S+)*)?\s*([\d\.]+)\s+([\d\.]+)\s+([\d\.]+)$
```

Regex Explanation:

- `^`: start of string
- `([\d\/]+)?`: **Group 1** (the date) - optional
- `\s+`: spaces
- `(\d+\.\d+)`: **Group 2** (the site)
- `\s+`: spaces
- `([A-Za-z]\S+(?:\s\S+)*)`: **Group 3** (the description)
- `\s+`: spaces
- `([A-Za-z]\S+(?:\s\S+)*)?`: **Group 4** (the description 2) - optional
- `\s*`: spaces - optional
- `([\d\.]+)`: **Group 5** (the quantity)
- `\s`: spaces
- `([\d\.]+)`: **Group 6** (the price)
- `\s`: spaces
- `([\d\.]+)`: **Group 7** (the total)
- `$`: end of string

You can access the single groups by their group number.

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/LR5Xqd/1).

Comment: This is great. However, I have noticed an issue in my data that I provided. A variation is not being parsed correctly. You can find the same [here](https://regex101.com/r/yOperm/1) the number `11` is parsed into group 4 and group 5 while it should be only in group 5. How can I modify the regex correctly?

Comment: Since descriptions should start with a letter, you may want to add that in the regex. Check the updated answer. @Rander